# Why don't I seem to get any random drops after Team Fortress 2 crashes?

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2

I was playing TF2 and suddenly the game crashed. I restarted the game again, however I didn't get any random drops afterwards. Even after the weekly drop reset time had passed (for me its on Friday, not on Thursday), I still didn't receive any drops.

I tried searching on the internet for answers and the only conclusions I could find was either I'd hit some 10 hours limit, or already received 9 items already. I even found someone who had this problem in 2013, they had this problem and it was fixed on its own after a few weeks. Others just went on and on without any items.

Is there any ways to make the TF2 random drop start dropping again?

Answer (score 5):

Drops are guaranteed to happen between 30 and 70 minutes of play time. On average this is about every 50 minutes, up to a max of ten 10 hours in one week.

You won't get any more item drops if you have played more than the 10 hours in a single week. The drops just stop. Your weekly playtime will reset at midnight GMT (+0) on Thursday.

There are a few requirements to be considered actively playing:

- Is connected to a VAC secured server.
- Is responding to in-game drop notifications while not utilizing external programs to do so.
- Is running only one instance of the game.
- Is not in textmode.

Verify that you aren't accidentally connecting to a non-VAC server, or that you don't have a second instance running.

Comment: i did everything correctly though..but what does the (text mode) mean

Comment: Starting the game with -textmode. If you are playing, I doubt you have it on.